# Navigate to different component from a component [React]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components, jsx

I have two components in src/components named as Comp1.js and Comp2.js

Comp1.js has following code:

```
export default class Comp1 extends Component{
  .... 
  render(){
    return(
      <h1>Comp1</h1>
      <div> In comp1 </div>
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Link to="/comp2"> Comp2 </Link>
          <Switch>
             <Router path="/comp2" component={Comp2} />
          </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

Comp2.js has following code:

```
export default class Comp2 extends Component{
 ...
 render(){
   return(
    <h1>Comp2</h1>
    <div> In comp2 </div>
   )
 }
}
```

Whenever I click link in Comp1, it redirects me to Comp2 but, it also shows header "Comp1", div "In comp1" and link. I want to just render Comp2 and get rid of Comp1 headers, div and link. Let me know if you need more clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move browser router wrapper to the main app root. This is how a react app routing is configured. Then you can use `<Link to="/comp2"> Comp2 </Link>` inside comp1 and navigate to the comp2 properly without having comp1 header when you are in the comp2.

```
import React from "react"
 import { render } from "react-dom"
 import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom"
 import Home from "./Home"
 import Comp1 from "./Comp1"
 import Comp1 from "./Comp2"

 const App = () => (
 <BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
   <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
   <Route path="/comp1" component={Comp1} exact />
   <Route path="/comp2" component={Comp2} exact />
 </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
)
```

Comp1,

```
export default class Comp1 extends Component{
  .... 
  render(){
    return(
      <h1>Comp1</h1>
      <div> In comp1 </div>
      <Link to="/comp2"> Comp2 </Link>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way, I can do everything inside Comp1. Since, going to App and configuring each and every link would be so cluttery

Comment: The problem is if you use browser router in somewhere, what actually happens is the routes inside it will render only inside browser router. So that would be the better put it like this. There is one thing you can do for sure rather that putting BroserRouter in app.js. Identify where should comp1 and comp2 be rendered. Put browser router there. Then import comp1 and comp2. But you have give it a try.

Comment: This worked perfectly! The trick is to leave App.js "empty" (without any stuff it's rendering to the screen). Then, set up the <Route path="/" component={Home} exact /> to point to your "homepage". That way, whenever the site loads, the screen won't be blank (because of App.js), the site will proceed to the homepage which will be rendered. Beautiful! @DushanRanasinghe you saved me from 10+ hours of trying to fix this issue! Asante sana!